# Javascript submenu toggle not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've made a toggle function for my menu when I click "Home" in nav bar it triggers its function and shows its sub menu no problem there but when I click "About" it should show it's own sub menu but instead it triggers the "Home" button function and  shows the "Home" button sub menu. Please see Snippet.

```js
    let getToggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
    let getLi = document.querySelector(".submenu");

function showHide () {

    if (getToggle.class == "toggle") {

        getLi.style.height = "0px";
        getLi.style.opacity = "0";
        getLi.style.visibility = "hidden";
        getToggle.class = "";
    } else {

        getLi.style.height = "110px";
        getLi.style.opacity = "1";
        getLi.style.visibility = "visible";
        getToggle.class = "toggle";
    }
}
```

```css
 * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }

body {
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    font-family:arial;
}

nav {
    background-color:white;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    transition:0.4s;
}

nav ul li {
      padding:5px 10px;
      display: inline-block;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;;
    color:grey;
}

nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width:100px;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    height:0px;
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li ><a href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="toggle" onclick="showHide()">&#9658;</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <a class="toggle" onclick="showHide()">&#9658;</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved word on JS so try changing `.class` to `.className` in the JS part. That's the proper way of accessing what you define in the class attribute on the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated script, to apply style on the target element only.

```
  function showHide(event) {

    var getToggle = event.target;
    var getLi = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    if (getToggle.class == "toggle") {

      getLi.style.height = "0px";
      getLi.style.opacity = "0";
      getLi.style.visibility = "hidden";
      getToggle.class = "";
    } else {

      getLi.style.height = "110px";
      getLi.style.opacity = "1";
      getLi.style.visibility = "visible";
      getToggle.class = "toggle";
    }
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: arial;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  ;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  ;
  color: grey;
}

nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: -10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="toggle" onclick="showHide(event)">&#9658;</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <a class="toggle" onclick="showHide(event)">&#9658;</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script>
  function showHide(event) {

    getToggle = event.target
    getLi = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    if (getToggle.class == "toggle") {

      getLi.style.height = "0px";
      getLi.style.opacity = "0";
      getLi.style.visibility = "hidden";
      getToggle.class = "";
    } else {

      getLi.style.height = "110px";
      getLi.style.opacity = "1";
      getLi.style.visibility = "visible";
      getToggle.class = "toggle";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please Can you explain this or give me a link to understand what you did. i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @AfaqQazi :)